# How to convert difftime to string "X hours Y minutes Z seconds"

Tags: r

I want to print a difftime object as a string like "X hours Y minutes Z seconds".

So instead of printing e.g. "1.034167 hours" I would like to see "1 hour 2 minutes 3 seconds".

```
library(hms)
difftime(hms(11, 02, 03), hms(10, 00, 00))
Time difference of 3.033611 hours

magicfunction(difftime(hms(11, 02, 03), hms(10, 00, 00)))
1 hour 2 minutes 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to convert to `period` if the `units` is `sec`onds

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(difftime(hms::hms(11, 02, 03), 
       hms::hms(10, 00, 00), units = 'sec'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

diff <- hms("11:02:03") - hms("10:00:00")

diff
# [1] "1H 2M 3S"

paste(diff$hour, "hours", diff$minute, "minutes", diff$second, "seconds")
# [1] "1 hours 2 minutes 3 seconds"
```

Comment: This didn't work quite as I expected: `hms("11:00:00") - hms("10:30:00")` gives `[1] "1H -30M 0S`. I need it to return `0H 30M 0S`.